# A string prefix in ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
ng-class="{{'tabs-'+currentStyle.value}}"

ng-class="'tabs-'{{currentStyle.value}}"

ng-class="tabs-{{currentStyle.value}}"
```

i am trying to apply a class based on a value, i tried all of the above and i always get

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'undefined' not a primary expression at column null of the expression [tabs-] starting at [tabs-].
```

what am i doing wrong?

i simply want the result to be `class="tabs-currentStyle.value"` without having to declare an extra variable in the scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you are trying to this:

```
ng-class="{true:'tabs-'+currentStyle.value}[true]"
```

Here is an **[Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZM3zL/)**

Comment: thank you works perfectly i tried true in the expression before but without the [true] in the end

Comment: I was trying to highlight the idea of this expression is to create a class an use it like an array in case you want a false expression to be part of it

Answer (score 5):

This also works:

```
ng-class="['tabs-'+currentStyle.value]">
```

Just tried it in Dalorzo's online demo.

Comment: 1+ for highlighting another expression possibility